# Pass parameter from JS to Struts2 Action method

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts2

The function in my `modify.jsp` is:

```
function getParamList() {
var accessTypeUnchanged = "0";
jPageDialog('Param Setting', '${ctx}/groupportal/functionInfo!detail.do?accessTypeUnchanged='+accessTypeUnchanged, 300, 360);
}
```

and The `detail()` method in `FunctionInfoAction.java` is:

```
@ExecuteResult(name="index")
public String detail(String accessTypeUnchanged) {
// SOME LOGIC CODE
return "detail";
}
```

the `getter` and `setter` methods have been added, but when I access the `getParamList()` from web page, a `NULLPOINTEREXECEPTION` accrued, what's the problem? Actually, the method `detail(String accessTypeUnchanged)` can't be accessed.

Answer (score 0):

I got it, the method shouldn't be `detail(String accessTypeUnchanged)`, it should be `detail()`.